# npm Error in Vs code using os Linux(Ubuntu)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular, react-native, npm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGJXx.png)

protons@protons-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/protons/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! dest /home/protons/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0/node_modules/.npm-IgU3U5Pl
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/protons/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0/node_modules/npm' -> '/home/protons/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0/node_modules/.npm-IgU3U5Pl'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/protons/.npm/_logs/2022-07-04T03_19_39_491Z-debug-0.log
protons@protons-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0$
protons@protons-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0$ sudo npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! code ENOTEMPTY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path /home/protons/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0/node_modules/npm
npm ERR! dest /home/protons/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0/node_modules/.npm-IgU3U5Pl
npm ERR! errno -39
npm ERR! ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rename '/home/protons/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0/node_modules/npm' -> '/home/protons/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0/node_modules/.npm-IgU3U5Pl'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-07-04T03_20_01_694Z-debug-0.log
protons@protons-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0$ ^C
protons@protons-HP-EliteBook-840-G3:~/Desktop/NH_Facility_Portal_V0$

Comment: Please don't just post your error messages, but at least a little text what you want to achieve. Screenshots are not suitable as well, as they cannot be copy-pasted e.g.. And please use the formatting possibilities provided for your contents.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the `node_modules` folder using `rm -r node_modules` and do `npm install`